# TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I keep getting this error when I try to run this script. It's for converting my google sheets data into JSON API.

TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")

```
function doGet(e) {

   var sheetName = "Sheet name";
   var sheetId   = "1234...";

   var book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
   var sheet = book.getSheetByName(sheetName);

   var json = convertSheet2JsonText(sheet);

   return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(json))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function convertSheet2JsonText(sheet) {
  // first line(title)
   var colStartIndex = 1;
   var rowNum = 1;
   var firstRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 2, sheet.getLastColumn());
   var firstRowValues = firstRange.getValues();
   var titleColumns = firstRowValues[0];

  // after the second line(data)
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var rowValues = [];
   for(var rowIndex=2; rowIndex<=lastRow; rowIndex++) {
   var colStartIndex = 1;
   var rowNum = 1;
   var range = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, colStartIndex, rowNum, 
sheet.getLastColumn());
   var values = range.getValues();
   rowValues.push(values[0]);
}

// create json
   var jsonArray = [];
   for(var i=0; i<rowValues.length; i++) {
   var line = rowValues[i];
   var json = new Object();
   for(var j=0; j<titleColumns.length; j++) {
     json[titleColumns[j]] = line[j];
   }
  jsonArray.push(json);
 }
 return jsonArray;
}
```

Is there anything you can see that would cause this error?

Comment: The sheet with the name you specify doesn't exist in the workbook you are using.

Comment: I use my sheet's name. I just used a demo name (Sheet name) here.

Comment: When you say "run this script", do you mean run from the Script Editor, or run the WebApp?

Comment: run from the Script Editor.

Comment: `I use my sheet's name. I just used a demo name (Sheet name) here.`  Regardless, The sheet name you entered in your actual script is wrong. Try changing your sheet name to  something simpler like `s1`

Comment: You can perform a simple check. Place the following line in `doGet` after your line that defines the `book` variable: `console.log({message: "all sheet names", names: book.getSheets().map(function (wksht) { return wksht.getName(); }) });` to view the results, *View -> Stackdriver Logs*

Comment: Yep, pretty simple. The code works fine in my testing. The problem is in `var firstRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 2, sheet.getLastColumn());`. This relies on the variable "sheet" which relies on your sheetName. Your error code means that this sheetname is invalid, non-existent or otherwise unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

The name of your sheet and/or the sheetID that you have used in your code is incorrect.

---

The error message = "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")"

> Line 20: var firstRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 2,
>   sheet.getLastColumn());

getRange is called by "sheet"; this means is that "sheet" is null.

You need to use the Script debug function (Run>Debug Function) to analyse your code. Run the debug on *doGet* - the debug will automatically include *convertSheet2JsonText* which is called by *doGet*.

I created some dummy data in a Sheet called "s1x", however, I deliberately assigned a 'sheetName' = "s1". Now when I run the Debug I get the same error message.

Line 20 is part of function *convertSheet2JsonText*, but the flaw isn't in this function; the error is in *doGet*.

Below is the debug screen showing the error. Note the value of "sheet" = null.
[image]

---

Below is the debug screen showing the values for *doGet*. Note the value of "sheet" is already null. But also note the value of sheetName = "s1". The only problem is that the actual value of the sheet is "s1x". That explains why "sheet" is null.

When I correct the value of sheetName, the function runs cleanly with no errors.
[image]

Comment: var sheetName = "BDCSylhet";
var sheetId   = "1_yHKdQeaq6EJsnjnK-Os77mukmA2qOJw6qqRSKVbTD4";
  
These are my sheetName and sheetId value. Correct value. Still facing the same problem.

Comment: problem solved. I needed to add the values to the convert function too.

Comment: Oops. My bad. But I'm glad you've got a result from it. Well done.