# TypeError when trying to use getRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, null, typeerror

<sup>NOTE: This is a proposal of canonical Q/A. Please discuss it on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420764/1595451)</sup>

As a new Google Apps Script user, I'm struggling about how to fix this error

This happen when using the default runtime

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

This happen when using the old runtime

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Bounded project

```
function myFunction(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('my sheet');
  sheet.getRange('A1');
}
```

Standalone project

```
function myFunction(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('put_here_a_spreadsheet_url');
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('my sheet');
  sheet.getRange('A1');
}
```

Using `getActiveSpredsheet()` and getRange directly from the `spreadsheet` variable

```
function myFunction(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the spreadsheet hasn't a sheet named `my sheet`. Please bear in mind that the `getSheetByName` parameter should be exactly the same as the sheet name:

- Same number of characters
- Same casing (uppercase / lowercase)
- The characters not only should look the same way, they should be the same i.e. a space looks similar to the human eye as a non-breaking-space but for the computers they aren't the same.

You might try typing the sheet name again both on the Google Sheets UI and on the Google Apps Script editor, or copy the name from one place and paste it into the other.

NOTE: You could use a variable name or put the sheet name directly inside the parenthesis. If you go for putting the sheet name inside the parenthesis it should be enclosed between `'` (apostrophe / straight single quote), `"` (straight double quote) or `` ` `` (grave accent / backtick).

The same error might happen when using `getActiveSpreadsheet()` or `getActiveSheet()` there is no active spreadsheet or active sheet
respectively. This usually happen when using these methods on stand-alone projects. In these cases, first you have to open the spreadsheet by using one of the following SpreadsheetApp methods `open(file)`, `openById(id)`, `openByUrl(url)`, then you might use `.activate()` before `getActiveSpreadsheet()` / `getActiveSheet()` methods.

Resources

- [Handling text — strings in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings)

Related (from oldest to newest)

- [JDBC Reading from a Database... TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13002218/)
- [Can't get Google Scripts working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22367010/)
- [TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52357590/)
- [Issue with protection script for google sheets - Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62112801/)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 6, file "Code") in google sheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62828787/)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 14, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62887346/)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null deleteRows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67228069/)
- [Issue with protection script for google sheets - Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62112801/)